# access hidden field value from javascript function in a separate file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

in my page1.aspx i have an hidden field where i need to get its value using javascript function in a seperate file. from page2.aspx i need to call this function in order to get the value of this hidden field but im getting NULL always.

below is my javascript function:

```
function gethashuser(){ 
return document.getElementById('hashuserid');
}
```

does anyone has a solution for this issue or any work around will be much appreciated.?
thank you in advance

Comment: I think you can use a `iframe` for this.

Comment: thank u for ur idea, currently im using 2 iframes; iframe1 containing page1.asp and iframe2 containing page2, but how to access element from iframe1 to iframe2?

Comment: `document.getElementById("youriframeid").contentwindow.yourfunction();`

Comment: didnt work, this method works fine if im calling from main content page not from another iframe.

Comment: are page 1 and page 2 on the same domain?

Comment: yes, under the same project, more precisely they are parts of the masterpage.